# TrackBar: no Scroll events in the list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I replaced my TrackBar with another TrackBar but when I look for the Scroll event of the new TrackBar I can't find it.

Here is the cole of the old TrackBar:

```
private void TrackBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
```

How can I create the Scroll event for the new TrackBar, as it doesn't exist in the event list?

Comment: I think we will need to know the types of the old and new trackbars. Without them, it's just a guess as to what to do

Comment: What do you mean by "type"?

Comment: If the *new TrackBar* doesn't expose a Scroll event, then it's not a TrackBar, or a standard TrackBar or you have selected another type of UI element

Comment: Ok thanks, I've recovered the TrackBar in this project ... in any case it looks like a TrackBar... If you have 2 minutes can you check if you find the "Scroll" event please?
https://github.com/kwwwvagaa/NetWinformControl/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the HZH_Controls in their Github, it would appear you need to handle the `ValueChanged` event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when [value changed].
/// </summary>
[Description("值改变事件"), Category("自定义")]
public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
```

Other parts of the code suggest that this event is raised when the Scrollbar is moved

Comment: Thanks, so if I've understood correctly the "ValueChanged" event replaces the "Scroll" event?

Comment: I wouldn't say replaced, the author chose to name the event `ValueChanged` instead of `Scroll`. I haven't looked deeply in to the control to see what it does or how it works, but if you are looking for an event that is raised when a scroll like action is performed, then I think `ValueChanged` is a good place to start.